# Python Indentation confusion of template code

Tags: python, indentation

I'm getting this error
`unindent does not match any outer indentation level` on the line

```
if line.find('ubox')>0
```

I'm not very experienced with python but pressing Shift Tab in my IDE does not fix the problem. This is the template code from one of my assignments so when I copy pasted it must have messed up the indentation. In the text file given, if lines up for but just eyeballing the code I would have thought it was a nested if in the elif.

```
def parse_dot_ps_file(filepath):
    '''
    Parsing of a dot.ps file that contains result of RNAfold program
    @args:
    filepath: (full or relative) path to the dot.ps.
    @return:
    dot_ps_result: list f lists with i, j, freq_i_j
    '''
    dot_ps_result = []
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        is_data = False
        for line in f:
            if not is_data and line.startswith('%start of base pair probability data'):
                is_data = True
                continue
            elif is_data and line.startswith('showpage'):
                break
            elif is_data:
        if line.find('ubox') > 0:
                    # take only first 3 numbers
                    data_line = line.split()[:3]
                    dot_ps_result.append(
                        [int(data_line[0]), int(data_line[1]), float(data_line[2])]
                    )
    return dot_ps_result
```

Comment: That `if` statement has to be indented relative to the `elif is_data`; it isn't in the code you show here, which would produce a *different* indentation error.

Comment: In Python, each block of code is introduced by a `:` and then *must* be indented *more* than the code around it.

Comment: Yes, this line should be nested in the elif block. Did you try it?

Comment: The reported error is what I would expect if you, for example, put `pass` in the `elif is_data` block, but then indented `if line.find...` by 3 spaces instead of 4 as is the previous code in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter expects something to be found under `elif is_data:`, but instead it found nothing. So either fill it with your code, or if you meant the line `if line.find('ubox') > 0:` to execute if the `elif is_data:` condition executes then fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if line.find('ubox') > 0:
# take only first 3 numbers
    #these two lines below are the problem 
    data_line = line.split()[:3]
    dot_ps_result.append([int(data_line[0]), int(data_line[1]), float(data_line[2])])
```

You also have an else statement with no code beneath it, so the indentation is hanging, what do you want the script to do there? All you need is `pass` and that would be fine

You have put too many tabs in this section.

Hope that helps